# The server may be running out of resources in aggregate functiond

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

I try to copy [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170061/Custom-Aggregates-in-SQL-Server?msg=4585040) code and to deploy this function to my server. When I try to create the function I get the message below. It's very strange to me because I don't use any unsafe resource.

I tried to run this with execute as 'dbo', and it's not helped me. I also tried to set `AUTHORIZATION` to `ON`.

> An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load
>   assembly id 65958.   The server may be running out of resources, or
>   the assembly may not be trusted with `PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
>   or UNSAFE`.   Run the query again, or check documentation to see how
>   to solve the assembly trust issues.   For more information about this
>   error:
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'exampleaggfunction, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly
>   name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>   System.IO.FileLoadException:
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved same problem.

Look's for solution here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/03/23/unable-to-load-clr-assembly-intermittently.aspx

1. Change the database's owner to sa which is gauranteed to match.

   USE your_db_name;
   ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::your_db_name TO SA;
   GO
2. Ensure that the db_owner's SID on from every database matches sys.server_principals and sys.databases:
   SELECT *
   FROM [master].[sys].[server_principals] -- here are SID of users

   SELECT *
   FROM [master].[sys].[databases] -- here information about databases

It helped me. May be it will be useful for you.